# VW Passat B5 1998 Eletronik issues

Tags: vw, passat

I noticed some strange behaviour in my Passat for a long time, the thing is: there are several small elecctrical issues that migh have the same source .. I noticed that when I turn on the ignition, the radio plays normaly (it used to stop while turning on engine), I have no sound in rear speakers out of nowhere (speakers worked for some weeks.. radio is ok, cables also are ok) and when I close the doors from the button on my driver door, the locks from rear doors pupus every time, so they close and open... Does anyone have a clue of what can be going wrong? (PS: I already had to change some cables that led to comfort control module)

Answer (score 1):

I had a VW B5 from 2001 - 2018, The B5 body has its comfort control module under the floor. The module and its wiring is subject to water-related damage, and the wiring's insulation fails with age.

These varied symptoms suggest that other wires, or the CCM itself, have been impaired, perhaps by water ingress. I'd start by removing the carpeting above the CCM, and making a careful inspection of the wiring. You had to change some wires; I would not be surprised if others have failed as well.

You should also carefully examine the small rubber drain lines from the sunroof, and the drains in the battery compartment below the battery; if any are blocked, they will allow water to enter the passenger compartment.

Comment: I will try that. I also have a water leak on driver floor and can't figure out where it cames from

Comment: Good luck. Another water source is condensate from the air conditioning evaporator. That usually manifests on the right side footwell.